# How to configure htaccess to display images from a directory other than the root directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am working with PHP and apache, and I have configured a router that shows me the images that are on the public site and root without problem, but when trying to show the images of the private site does not load them.

[image: test]

I need to save images on the private site and show them only to the owners, I don't think saving the images on the public site is ideal.

The router is configured so that all routes publicly begin with "/" and not "../".

How could I solve this locally and have it work correctly on a real server?.

//project structure:

```
app/
-------/public     <======Root
---------------/css
---------------/img
---------------/js
---------------/index.php
---------------/.htaccess
-------/private
---------------/imgs    
---------------/pages
---------------/dashboard.php
-------/lib
-----------/route.php`
```

//.htaccess config

```
AddType Content-Type: application / x-www-form-urlencoded

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php? [QSA,L]
```

//html

```
    <span> <img src="img/test2.jpg" width="30px"> </span>
   <span> <img src="../private/imgs/test1.jpg" width="30px"> </span>
```

//php try

```
<?php
    $directorio = "../private/imgs/";

    function printImagesDir($dir){
        $files = glob($dir.'*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}', GLOB_BRACE);
        foreach($files as $filename){
            $imgsrc = basename($filename);
            echo "<img src='{$dir}/{$imgsrc}' />";
        }        
    }

    printImagesDir($directorio);
?>
```

Comment: (Unrelated) fyi: the `width` attribute doesn't take any units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route all your images into one script file that will fetch images (or even validate if current logged in user is valid to access that).

```
# .htaccess

# Adjust regex to your needs
RewriteRule images/(\w+\.(?:\w{3,4}))$ images.php?image=$1 [L]
```

```php
// public/images.php

$image = $_GET['image'] ?? null;

if (empty($image)) {
    throw new Exception('Image not found');
}

$name = dirname(__DIR__) . '/private/imgs/' . $image;
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// Change header depending on file extension!
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));

fpassthru($fp);

// Terminate further output or image can get corrupt
exit(0);
```

and finally in HTML just request that URL:

```html
<img src="images/test1.jpg"/>
<img src="images.php?image=test1.jpg"/>
```

Comment: I understand the proposal, but when adding the line to the .htaccess they do not load the CSS styles and JS files.
I can see that the images do not load, and when writing only the line that it proposes, it does not find the page (error 404)

Comment: @Xh2ox Well, you redirect _everything_ to `index.php`: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php? [QSA,L]`

Comment: @Xh2ox So maybe exclude resources?

Comment: without modifying htaccess it works for a single image. But when passing more parameters, for example user ID, would I have to modify the "images.php" or do I just add the parameter in the html?

Comment: @Xh2ox Don't you have user information in session? Modify regex to allow user ID in URL if needed

Comment: If I add the line of code that you proposed for htaccess, the images, CSS and JS styles are not loaded. The modification of the url with regex would be in the images.php file?.Yes, I have session data, but I need to show the images of the products that the user creates by accessing subfolders, for example: private/imgs/user-a/product-b/test1.jpg. htaccess makes it difficult for me to access private folders. I really don't know how to configure htaccess. Your code works I guess if I save all the images in a single folder. Thank you, you helped me solve the first part of the problem

Comment: @Xh2ox Well, you can change to something like `^images/(.*?\.(?:\w{3,4}))$` or even `^images/(.*)$`, so that you would accept anything after `images`. Just make sure you validate your input, not to allow something like `images/../../../path/to/configuration/file.php`